# Does Facebook re-authentication needed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I got this message on last thursday.

Recent updates in our app permission policies applied a 90-day expiration to user permissions (permissions pertaining to a user's profile info such as posts, photos, gender, age range). 
Effective immediately, this now applies to {my-app}

I have read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/auth-vs-data, and tried to check what happen when after data_access_expires_at time. I wanted to know how API responses change.

However, I found no documents of neither consequence for being out-dated nor way of make access token be out-dated.

I do have procedure for re-gaining access token when an access token is invalid. But does this procedure covers in the case of re-authentication needed?

Comment: _“But does this procedure covers in the case of re-authentication needed?”_ - It requires that the login dialog is called with parameter `auth_type: 'reauthorize'`.

Comment: @isorude Thanks for answer. But how it works for android and iOS? If I try to login with token which data access expired, do I blocked from login?

Comment: No, login and data access are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not offer 'reauthorize' but you can build it on your own. Facebook also does not offer a programmatic way to extend tokens. What they do say however if users that authenticate your app remain active with your app - their tokens will never expire. If they are not active with your app - access only lasts 90 days.

What you need to do is to place Facebook's login script on your pages. This basically establishes the 'activity":

```html
<script>
    
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {            
            // don't have to do anything actually
        });
        
        FB.init({
            appId            : '${facebookAppId}',
            autoLogAppEvents : true,
            status : true, // check login status
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v3.2'
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```